# Server with multiclients via thread

Tags: java, networking, tcp, game-development

I'm having a bit of trouble, now I have looked at this tutorial
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html
This tutorial gives you a server that multiple clients can connect to, when they connect to the server they are told to go along with a knock knock job, now I understand how to transfer the data and what not, but how does the threads work?

I'm working on a networked pong game where a server will hold the positions and pass them to the clients, now I have a client connected to the server and the ball position is passed to the client, works fine, a bit jumpy but I'm sure a thread with .sleep will help. but anyways my question is, how can i get my client to become a thread? and how can I store them?

For example here is the knock knock server multiThread class

```
package knockKnockServer;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KKMultiServerThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket = null;

public KKMultiServerThread(Socket socket) {
super("KKMultiServerThread");
this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {

try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine, outputLine;
    KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
    out.println(outputLine);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
    out.println(outputLine);
    if (outputLine.equals("Bye"))
        break;
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

And here in the server we have

```
package knockKnockServer;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MultiKKServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    boolean listening = true;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while (listening)
    new KKMultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

    serverSocket.close();
}
}
```

Now looking at the server it will create a new KKMultiServerThread on each connection, but how can i store them? can i make a array of KKMultiServerThread?
I tried to make an array of KKMultiServerThread
and when i try this line

```
multi[0] = new KKMultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
```

I get this error "cannot convert void to Thread"
If anyone can shine some light on my problem it would be great.

Canvas

Update

I now have my own thread class

```
package Pong;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PongPlayerThread extends Thread 
{
private Socket socket = null;
private String pongData = "";

public PongPlayerThread(Socket socket, int id) 
{
    super("PongPlayerThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void passData(String data)
{
    pongData = data;
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(true)
        {
            out.println(pongData);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

the pongData is a string that holds all the information together in a string, now if i declare a player1 at the top of my pong server like so

```
private static PongPlayerThread player1;
```

and do this line when it is listening

```
    while(listen)
    {
        PongPlayerThread player1 = new PongPlayerThread(serverSocket.accept(), 0).start();
    }
```

it gives me this error "cannot convert from void to PongPlayerThread" how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array declaration is missing the object type

```
KKMultiServerThread multi[0] = new KKMultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
```

Why bother though? Unless the threads needs to communicate with each other, letting the threads run freely is ok. The Run() method defines the entire lifetime of the socket as far as the server is concerned.  Each thread has a separate copy of the state of the game (as long as you don't use statics) and will happily communicate with the client without any extra intervention.

This is a case where the Socket/Thread library in Java is doing you a big favor, don't make it more complicated unless you have a specific need.

Comment: ok here is the other problem, when a client connects the first client needs to be able to control the bat on the right of the screen, the second client needs to control the left bat of the screen, how can i tell which client is which?

Also the line you gave me says KKMultiServerThread can not be resolved to a variable

Comment: You could create specific thread instances like player1 (left) and player2 (right) and change the server to only accept two connections before it stops listening. Then the code for the player has a simple flag that tells it which side it should be.

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: @Canvas check my modified answer to give you clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When ever a client connects to the server. The server will typically create a new thread specifically for that client. Here is some pseudo code:

```
WHILE SERVER IS RUNNING

SERVER WAITS FOR A CLIENT TO CONNECT
SERVER ACCEPTS THE CLIENT IF THERE IS ENOUGH MEMORY TO CREATE A NEW THREAD
SERVER CREATES A NEW THREAD ROUTINE FOR THE CLIENT PASSING THE CLIENT INFORMATION TO THE THREAD
SERVER CONTINUES TO LISTEN WHILE EACH THREAD IS SPECIFICALLY TAILORED FOR THE CLIENTS

REPEAT
```

You asked what steps are needed to reduce lag? Well for starters, set a maximum allowed connections. You do not want 5000 clients having their own thread. Unless your machine can handle all that and still run. Use UDP instead of TCP, and data compression try to minimize bandwidth don't send 50 GB of information at a time; if all you need is a couple of bytes of information to send. Try to send information of positions not as strings but in bytes. For example you can send the position X=5Y=0 as 50 and parse the first decimal digit as X and the second decimal digit as Y.

Instead of passing the client socket inside the thread routine pass a unique identifier for the client. Since Pong is two players limit the connections to two clients. 0 for Player 1 and 1 for Player 2. So

```
new KKMultiServerThread(clientID).start(); // clientID is of type int
```

**Edit:**

```
int id = 0;
while(serverIsRunning)
{
    Client client = server.accept();
    if (id > 2) client.Close(); // Do not accept.
    Thread.New(id).Start();
    id++;
}
```

Comment: The pong game needs to be made in TCP/IP first then UDP :D

Comment: Okay I will scratch the UDP Part.

Comment: ok so the constructor takes in a int for its clientID, but for the input how would i check it for that id?

new KKMultiServerThread(clientID).start(); // clientID is of type int

But the constructor i have is given a socket? Should it take a socket and clientID?

Comment: Simple keep a counter of clients connected, since Pong requires two players then the first player will  have an ID of zero  and the second will have an ID of 1.

Comment: then inside the KKMultiServerThread that will deal with if the bat should move up and down yea?

Comment: Is it possible if I custom my code now, and come back to this later? Shame there isn't PM on stackoverflow

Comment: @Canvas Wait now I see, change the constructor to accept the socket and the id so they are two argument.

Comment: Ok, I have not yet implemented the multiThread to work with my pong server yet, once i get that i will let you know if I have anymore problems :)

Comment: Ok daniel i have constructed a thread class, but the thread needs data to be passed into all the time, i will update my question with my new code :)

Comment: Also what is the Client? is that a class you made up?